# Correct use of polymorphism and inheritance for some logic

Tags: java, oop

I have basic class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_model_query")
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="query_type",
public abstract class Query {

    private String dmlQuery;

    private String ddlQuery;

    //getters and setters 
}
```

And two child. SimpleQuery:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SIMPLE")
public class SimpleQuery extends Query {

    private ConnectionInfo connectionInfo; //initialize via constructor or setter

    public Integer getConnectionId() {
        return connectionInfo.getId();
    }

}
```

SummaryQuery:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("COMPLEX")
public class SummaryQuery extends Query {

    private List<SimpleQuery> children;

}
```

In some service, I want add some logic for validate sql query. I created method:

```
@Service
class SomeService {
    //some business logic
    @Autowired
    private final DataExtractorService dataExtractorService;

    private void validateQueries(Query query) {
        if (query instanceof SimpleQuery) {
            String sqlQuery = ((SimpleQuery) query).getSqlQuery();
            Integer connectionId = ((SimpleQuery) query).getConnectionId();
            //validate by sqlQuery and connectionId
            dataExtractorService.tryToextractOneRecord(connectionId , sqlQuery);
        } else {
            SummaryQuery summaryQuery = (SummaryQuery) query;
            List<SimpleQuery> children = ((SummaryQuery) query).getChildren();
            children.forEach(query -> dataExtractorService.tryToextractOneRecord(query.getConnectionId(), query.getSqlQuery());
        }
    }
}
```

In this solution, I strongly dislike the use of `if` check, as well as the use of `instanceof`. What if I had more than two inheritors, the code would be too huge and I need to remember to add another `if`. This is not a OOP approach. How could this problem be solved?

**EDIT**:

Query validation is essentially executing it on the DB. For this you need ddlQuery and connectionId. To do this, you need a service for working with the database. I can't inject it in POJO classes, because of this I can't implement the validate() method

Comment: That depends on your design. The simplest approach is to have each query have it's own `validate()` method.

Comment: Why does your `SomeService` validate SQL queries? Is it really the job of `SomeService` to do that?

Comment: This is the work of the service, because I inject other services into it to work with the database, and so on. I can't embed this in my POJO classes, since this is the DB entity

Comment: As the previous commenter mentioned, I'd also have an abstract validate method, which each of the children implement. Then you could iterate through `List<Query>` and call validate methods on each of them, perhaps returning `true` and `false` respectively. That way your service wouldn't need to use `instanceof`, but could concentrate on working with the queries upon making sure they're valid. But yeah: it all depends on your design. You might also use an interface instead of the abstract class, but then you wouldn't be able to define common attributes. The question is whether you need them.

Comment: @Igor, Query validation is essentially executing it on the DB. For this you need `ddlQuery` and `connectionId`. To do this, you need a service for working with the database. I can't inject it in POJO classes, because of this I can't implement the `validate()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extension of Herber Marshall response.
I want to start saying that if your problem is:

> This is not a OOP approach. How could this problem be solved?

Herber Marshall is the correct answer, covering basic use cases, to cover more complex case, we should start from there, making the code more complex.

The pattern suggested is very simple and elegant, but seems it can't be applied because in the `validate` method you require to use a service that can't be injected in your DTO (good practice).

As first step check if it is a good fit passing that service into the `validate` method as an argument (so, all your cases can be implemented using the same service/dependency). If that is true go for that solution.

In your code seems that all the cases (if branches) use the same service object to implement their logic, this response is for cases in which this doesn't apply, or you need different number of services for each branch.

Let's add another query type to make an example:

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DIFFERENT")
public class DifferentQuery extends Query {

    private Something something; //initialize via constructor or setter

    public Integer getConnectionId() {
        return something.getConnectionInfo().getId();
    }

}
```

And changing your validation logic as:

```java
@Service
class SomeService {
    //some business logic
    @Autowired
    private final DataExtractorService dataExtractorService;

    @Autowired
    private final SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    private void validateQueries(Query query) {
        if (query instanceof SimpleQuery) {
            String sqlQuery = ((SimpleQuery) query).getSqlQuery();
            Integer connectionId = ((SimpleQuery) query).getConnectionId();
            //validate by sqlQuery and connectionId
            dataExtractorService.tryToextractOneRecord(connectionId , sqlQuery);
        } else if (query instanceof SummaryQuery){
            SummaryQuery summaryQuery = (SummaryQuery) query;
            List<SimpleQuery> children = ((SummaryQuery) query).getChildren();
            children.forEach(query -> dataExtractorService.tryToextractOneRecord(query.getConnectionId(), query.getSqlQuery());
        }
        else {
             DifferentQuery dQuery = (DifferentQuery) query;
             String sqlQuery = someOtherService.retrieveSql(dQuery);
             dataExtractorService.tryToextractOneRecord(query.getConnectionId(), sql);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case to be "more OOP" what we should do is using a mix of double dispatch, and visitor pattern.

As first thing we should have an interface to manage validation for all the types of queries:

```java
interface QueryValidation {
    void validate(SimpleQuery query);
    void validate(SummaryQuery query);
    void validate(DifferentQuery query);
}
```

This interface will be passed to the `validate` method added to your `Query` type:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_model_query")
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="query_type",
public abstract class Query {

    private String dmlQuery;

    private String ddlQuery;

    //getters and setters 

    public abstract void validate(QueryValidation validation);
}
```

Your types extending query will use that service to implement the `validate` method:

```java
public class SimpleQuery extends Query {

    private ConnectionInfo connectionInfo;

    public Integer getConnectionId() {
        return connectionInfo.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(QueryValidation validation) {  //  <----
        validation.validate(this);
    }

}
```

In this way all your query types will need to have a validation, all of them implement `validate` in this way, so that if you forget to add a validation for a type in the `QueryValidation` interface, your code will not compile.

Then you will have to implement the `QueryValidation` interface and use it in your main service:

```java
class QueryValidationImpl implements QueryValidation{
    @Autowired
    private final DataExtractorService dataExtractorService;

    @Autowired
    private final SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    public void validate(SimpleQuery query) {
        String sqlQuery = query.getSqlQuery();
        Integer connectionId = ((SimpleQuery) query).getConnectionId();
        //validate by sqlQuery and connectionId
        dataExtractorService.tryToextractOneRecord(connectionId , sqlQuery);
    }
    public void validate(SummaryQuery query) {
        List<SimpleQuery> children = query.getChildren();
        children.forEach(query -> 
        dataExtractorService.tryToextractOneRecord(query.getConnectionId(), query.getSqlQuery());
    }
    public void validate(DifferentQuery query){
        String sqlQuery = someOtherService.retrieveSql(query);
        dataExtractorService.tryToextractOneRecord(query.getConnectionId(), sql);
    }
}

@Service
class SomeService {
    //some business logic
    @Autowired
    private final QueryValidation queryValidation;

    private void validateQueries(Query query) {
       query.validate(queryValidation);
    }
}
```

With this solution you avoid using the `instanceof` and all the `if` letting the compiler doing them for you.
I find this as an heavy solution, and required only for few cases.
Most of the times having `if else if` using `instanceof` is not so bad, and if you look to "newer" languages (kotlin, scala) they have `sealed` types that is another way to do it. It is what in functional programming is called "pattern matching" and there it is a good practice (but in FP you have also some useful tools provided by the lang to be safe and avoid boilerplate)

Watch out that you can use this only if you have a closed set of types (you know/are in control of all the classes extending `Query`), if you need them to be an open set (who use this can implement its own `Query` type and can't change the `QueryValidation` interface), you will need to make it more complex introducing generics in the query.
This is true also for the `if else if` way, if you want end users to add their own types of query, letting them implement the validation logic, you will require some other strategy.
I sometimes use to have a `Map<Class, Logic>` retrieving from the map the right `Logic` to apply, but this as some cons too but I think this is another topic.

What I suggest is use a solution that covers all the cases that you know **now**, because an entire book can be wrote to solve this kind of issues in a "generic" way.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for describing it in such detail. Now I have a better understanding of how to work with this

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your Query class:

```
public abstract class Query {

    private String dmlQuery;

    private String ddlQuery;

    //getters and setters 

    public abstract boolean validate();  //  <----
}
```

Then implement the method in your children classes

```
public class SimpleQuery extends Query {

    private ConnectionInfo connectionInfo;

    public Integer getConnectionId() {
        return connectionInfo.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate() {  //  <----
        //Simple Query validation code here
    }

}
public class SummaryQuery extends Query {

    private List<SimpleQuery> children;

    @Override
    public boolean validate() {  //  <----
        //Summary Query validation code here
    }

}
```

Then all you have to do is call that method.  Any additional Query classes will be forced to define a validate method.

```
class SomeService {
    //some business logic

    private void validateQueries(Query query) {
         // Some logic
         boolean isValid = query.validate();
         // Other logic
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work. This is the work of the service, because I inject other services into it to work with the database, and so on. I can't embed this in my POJO classes, since this is the DB entity. `Query` is a DB Enity, so, POJO

Comment: @All_Safe Maybe you should have clarified that in your question.

Comment: What if you pass the service to the `validate` method as a parameter?